# How do I check if my PowerShell is connected on SSH?

Tags: windows, powershell, security

I know how to check but command line cmd or powershell can be altered to make it look clean with disguised hash codes (which they show like they are not tempered but actually commands are altered and edited) or even faked Also I don’t trust the services.msc for same reason.

Is there any trustable 100% method to understand it?

Comment: "Is there any trustable 100% method to understand it?" - disconnect the machine from any network, kill all radio components, glue the physical interfaces shut :)